# Limiting the fields returning in a JSON endpoint

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an endpoint where I want to allow the caller to limit the # of fields returned in the JSON result.

```
case class User(id: Int, p1: String, p2: String, p3: Int, p4: Boolean, ...)
```

controller action looks like:

```
 def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    val user = userService.get(...)
    Ok(user)
  }
```

So say the endpoint can be called like:

```
/user/123
/user/123?fields=p1,p3
```

Since I have a user case class, how could I possible manipulate the result set in a dynamic way based on what the caller wants returned?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just filter JSON fields:

```scala
case class Lorem(foo: String, bar: Int)

implicit val format: OFormat[Lorem] = Json.format

val fields = List("foo")

Ok(JsObject(
  Json.toJsObject(Lorem("str", 2)).value.filterKeys(fields.contains)))

//{"foo":"str"}
```